# How to combine two robot models in gazebo?

Tags: gazebo, urdf, xacro, p3dx, kinova

I have two robots, one is P3Dx and the other is Kinova Gen3 lite. I want to create a mobile manipulator combining these two robots. I have the respective packages and they contain the URDF files. How do I combine the URDFs? Also, since the robots are controlled differently. How do I make sure they can be operated as one robot? What other things I need to take care of?